# Recursive function to get all possible combination in Java

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I am trying to find all possible combination of the expert for skill in a particular project with a recursive function. But I'm getting the wrong answer.

I have an expert list for each project. I can access the expert list for each skill by

```
ExpertForSkill currentExpertList = currentProjectTeam.expertForSkill.get(skillNum);
```

My recursive function is

```
    public static List<ProjectAndTeam> recursiveExpertFinder(
        int skillNum,
        ProjectAndTeam currentProjectTeam,
        List<ProjectAndTeam> projectAndTeams) {

    if (skillNum == currentProjectTeam.project.skills.size()) {
        return projectAndTeams;
    } else {
        ExpertForSkill currentExpertList = currentProjectTeam.expertForSkill.get(skillNum);
        ExpertForSkill newExprtForSkill = new ExpertForSkill();
        ProjectAndTeam newProjectAndTeam = new ProjectAndTeam();
        newProjectAndTeam.project = currentProjectTeam.project;
        for (Expert expert : currentExpertList.expertList) {

            newExprtForSkill.skill = currentExpertList.skill;
            newExprtForSkill.expertList.add(expert);
            List<ExpertForSkill> newExpertList = new ArrayList<>();
            newExpertList.add(newExprtForSkill);
            newProjectAndTeam.expertForSkill = newExpertList;
            projectAndTeams.add(newProjectAndTeam);
           recursiveExpertFinder(skillNum + 1, currentProjectTeam, projectAndTeams);
        }
        return projectAndTeams;


    }


}
```

I'm calling the recursive function like

```
List<ProjectAndTeam> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
projectAndTeam = recursiveExpertFinder(0, currentProjectTeam, solutions);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
My expert list is like

```
Skill 1 : A,B
Skill 2 : B
```

I'm expecting the output like

```
Skill 1:A
Skill 2:B

Skill 1:B
Skill 2:B
```

but I'm getting the output same as input

```
Skill 1 : <A,B>
Skill 2 : <B>
```

Comment: What's the correct answer and what's the wrong answer you are getting?

Comment: I have edited my question with expected output and my current output

Comment: Isn't this what your recursive function doing, its terminating condition is when `skillNum == currentProjectTeam.project.skills.size()`. So, if Skill size is 2, resulting output would contain 2 items and so on.